# How can I use composer to add a third party module in magento

Tags: magento, composer-php

I want to add a [third party module](http://mobiledetect.net/) in magento with composer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically interested in the mobile connect class, then you don't need to use Composer.  The project GitHub repository links to [this Magento Connect module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16835/), which implements a Magento module to give you the the class functionality as a Magento helper.

Generally speaking, there's no great way to use Composer on Magento 1.  (Magento 2, Beta due out December 18th, is a different story).  You can create a new `composer.json` file in your root repository and installed composer packages as-per-normal (making sure not to deploy `composer.json` to your actual web root), but Magento 1 doesn't have a native composer autoloader implementation, and Magento's native autoloader (the `Varien_Autoload` class) shoves itself on the autoloader stack first and **fails** if it can't find a class.  This means you need to do a lot of autoloader shuffling to get Composer's autoloader on there first.

The ins and out of this are all a little much for a single Stack Overflow answer.  I [wrote an article](http://alanstorm.com/php_composer_magento_tutorial) on using composer to install Magento modules (this won't cover your standard packages), and you might be intersted in the [composer documents](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) on working with frameworks.

I'd start trying to do this yourself, and when you get stuck on a specific part come back with a specific questions.

Good look!

Comment: Thank you for guidance, I had already seen that module but my manager wants to add this module using composer. I will try today and come back with question(S) if any. Thanks again for writing.